# How to install XMP Toolkit on mac os x mojave

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to use `XMP Toolkit` for manipulating my `jpg` files' `metadata`.

By installing, I need `Exempi` and `boost`, but I am somewhat stuck at `installation` of them. I tried to install them with brew, but documentation says exempi needs boost to compile

> "./configure --with-boost=/usr/local # (for Homebrew)" .

What should I do now? Could someone be so kind and help me, maybe with a little step-by step guide for noobs? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `brew install exempi` and homebrew should install Boost and other dependencies that are needed.